# Route configuration in AngularJS is not giving expected results

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code in the script file:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider

            .when("/index", {
                templateUrl: "Views/post.html"
                })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo:"/"
            })

        })
```

So when the URL is http://localhost:55657/index.html, it should show "Views/post.html" , i.e. the post.html view in the ng-view directive of index page. Following is a snippet from my index.html page:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
```

But it is not showing anything when I load index.html. Following error is shown on browser console:

> [Error: $injector:modulerr
>   Module Error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.5%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dfn%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520string%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55657%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A6%3A416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Ob%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55657%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A19%3A393)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20pb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55657%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A19%3A480)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Wb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55657%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A34%3A17)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.e%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55657%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A36%3A178)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55657%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A35%3A23)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55657%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A35%3A147%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55657%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A7%3A302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55657%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A34%3A428)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Lb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55657%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A38%3A146)

Comment: Show the order of your `<script>` tags; `angular-route.js` should come after `angular.js`. Check if you have `ng-app="app"`. (Use `<div ng-view></div>` instead)

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate to "http://localhost:55657/index.html" it will load up the "/" route. Because it looks up the '#/' part after the html. You don't have any routes that matches with that.
The *otherwise* path does not match with any of your routes either.

You can fix this by renaming your '/index' *path definition* to '/' or use '/index' in your *otherwise* path.

For example:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

        .when("/index", {
            templateUrl: "Views/post.html"
            })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:"/index"
        })

    })
```

Related pages:

- Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider
- Example: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp